# How to find $f(x)$ that is sitting inside an integral?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functions, definite-integrals

**Question:** Find $f(x)$ if $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{2x}{a^2-x^2}f(x)dx=C$ where $a$ and $C$ are constants that are independent of $x$.

**My Attempts:**
I tried to apply integration by parts.

Take $u=f(x)$, $dv=\displaystyle \frac{2x}{a^2-x^2}dx$.

Then, $du=f'(x)dx$ and $v=-\ln|a^2-x^2|$.

Thus, $C=\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{2x}{a^2-x^2}f(x)dx=[-\ln|a^2-x^2|f(x)]_0^1+\int_0^1\ln|a^2-x^2|f'(x)dx$.

It seems like things are getting more complicated. How do I proceed from here? Or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: So given $a$ and $C$ you want to find a function $f$ such that $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{2x}{a^2-x^2}f(x)dx=C$ holds? Or all functions with that property? –  One could easily *guess* $f(x) = C(a^2-x^2)$, but I doubt that the solution is unique.

Comment: Actually you can start with (almost) *any* continuous function on $[0, 1]$ and then scale it such that the equation holds. – Are you sure that the problem is stated correctly and completely?

Comment: I am supposed to find all functions (or a general solution function).

Comment: The class of functions satisfying this is very vast if you don't impose other conditions, in fact any function $f$ such that the resulting integral assumes a finite value can be scaled appropriately to satisfy your conditions.